# Batch command to ignore specific files after dir command?

Tags: batch-file

How do I set a batch script to ignore certain files? Like, not filter, but exact files. 
Like

```
dir /b *.zip
```

Results in the file list

```
file1.zip
file2.zip
file3.zip
file4.zip
file5.zip
```

And I want to ignore the specific files

```
file3.zip
file4.zip
```

And end up with the file list result

```
file1.zip
file2.zip
file5.zip
```

How do I do this?

Comment: check this article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490905.aspx

Comment: I can't seem to find what I'm looking for in that article. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
dir /b *.zip|findstr /v /i /g:"filecontainingexcludednamesonetoaline.txt"
```

should handle this task quite adequately.

---

On more information provided (best to provide relevant information at the start to prevent an endless revision cycle)

```
...
dir /b *.zip|findstr /x /v /i /g:"~f0"
....
goto :eof
---- this info at end-of-file. just plain text
---- files-to-exclude-from-listing
---- these last 3 lines are just comments playing no part in the script
exclude me.zip
and_me.zip
dont_show me.zip
```

Comment: This works perfectly Magoo. Only one problem, is the batch script I'm working on is intended to be published in one single file. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You should add the `/L` option to force interpretation of the search terms as string literals. Without it, FINDSTR sees the dot in file1.txt and sees it as a regular expression wildcard, so all search terms are treated as regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly the same as Magoo's answer, but without the extra file, and also with the addition of the /L option to force a literal match:

```
dir /b *.zip|findstr /vilx /c:"file1.zip" /c:"file2.zip"
```

This is a bit overkill for this problem, but you could also use my [JREN.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081). It is primarily intended for renaming files, but it does have an option to list files instead. The advantage of this utility is it allows you to specify very precise regular expression terms to match, as well as to specify files to exclude.

In this case, I use the /FM and /FX options to specify masks with normal Windows wildcard rules instead of using regular expressions.

```
jrepl "^" "" /list /fm *.zip /fx "file1.zip|file2.zip"
```

If you have complicated matching rules, then /RFM and /RFX could be used to specify regular expression masks instead.